# spark scala create map from list in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the schema as below:

```
   root
   |-- id: string (nullable = true)
   |-- info: array (nullable = true)
   |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
   |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- _2: long (nullable = false)
   |    |    |-- _3: string (nullable = true)
```

I want the o/p to be:

```
  id | info
  111|[{aaa:{12,abc}},{xxx:{14,def}}]
  222|[{ddd:{23,fgh}},{jjj:{13,ijk}}]
  333|[{aaa:{96,wer}]
```

Please help

Comment: can you share the schema of your dataframe?

Comment: i will share u. Info is array of structs. I wana the first field of that array (info._1 to be the key and remaining as values) basically key value pair

Comment: Hi Ramesh, i have updated with schema

Comment: why did you delete the input? please post the input dataframe and schema both

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your "info" field contains a list, and you want to turn the first element of each list to be the key of that list.

Maybe try:

```
    dataset.map(row => row.getAs[Seq[Row]]("info") 
           .map(list => Map (list.head, list.tail)))
```

I'm new to Scala too. And since I don't know your specific schema, the above code might not work as expected. Hope this is helpful.